# Why is Drinfeld's Zastava space called Zastava?

Tags: etymology, ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

I'm trying to get an idea of [Drinfeld's Zastava space](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9707010). It seems to be an infinite-dimensional version of the flag variety, for affine Lie algebras.

But, first of all, why is it called Zastava (Застава)? Sadly I don't understand Russian and I don't understand the connotation. Googling gave me [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zastava) about a car company first. But I don't think a car company has much to do with these spaces, or does it?

Apparently it means "outpost" in Russian. But why an outpost? Drinfeld seems to be Ukrainian (again, from Wikipedia) and zastava means "pledge"?

Is it an outpost to a greater understanding of these spaces? Is it a pledge of mathematicians to understand more???

Comment: +1 for trying all the obvious things first!


Comment: I've never heard about the Ukranian meaning "pledge" for "zastava" (which is, BTW, an old word in Slavic). My dictionary returns "1) (histor.) gate, turnpike; 2) (military) outpost; picket, security detachment." To my taste, "turnpike" is better than "outpost" and you may count *flags* as *pikes.*

Comment: The word "zastava" means "flag" in Croatian (or Serbian). 
I. Mirkovic is Croatian, so maybe that's the explanation. 


Comment: Antun, that's indeed a nice etymologic reason. I would suggest you putting your comment as answer.

Comment: @Wadim: all my Slavic is based on http://translate.google.com ... Please blame google:p What did zastava mean in proto-Slavic, say in the church Slavonic?  @Antun; thanks! I'll accept your answer once you post it below. So it just meant the flag space ... 

Comment: Yuji, it's too late to blame translate.google, at least in Oz. Sometimes it's quite efficient...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The term was coined by one Michael de Finkelberg during his visit to Croatia. The word is indeed Croatian and means ``flag''. I was happy to have a Croatian word in mathematics.
The strategy of giving a new notion an old name but in a different language is not perfect.

Comment: I've certainly heard of worse naming strategies....

Comment: Now, how do you translate "flag variety" in Croatian?

Comment: I think they would write/say "fleg varijetet", as that is how I would write it in Serbian. So there would be no problems in understanding. Similar occurrence happened in maths, with complex/symplectic, as the same word (complex) was borrowed from the greek word (symplectikos) to coin the new kind of geometry.

Answer (score 11):

The word "zastava" means "flag" in Croatian (or Serbian). I. Mirkovic, one of the authors of the paper linked by Yuji, is Croatian, so maybe that's the explanation.

Comment: I've heard that zaszlo is "flag" in Hungarian, but didn't think it had any relation to my name (probably originally Zaslowski and Ukrainian) -- Uralic vs. Slavic.  In any case I will now try harder to understand flag varieties.

Comment: Whatever the case, the Hungarian word "zaszlo" is of Slavic origin. 